# SDL_GetError() returning an undocumented error on macOS

Tags: c, sdl, sdl-2

So I am developing [a set of wrapping utilities for SDL2](https://github.com/Th3T3chn0G1t/SDL_Wrapper) but have come across a strange issue. Whenever I poll for errors using `SDL_GetError` at the end of a frame, if I am touching the trackpad I get the following strange error message: `Unknown touch device id -1, cannot reset`. This error in quotes only shows [one result on google](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy/issues/966#issuecomment-560386829) and it seems to be an issue with macOS though with only one occurrence it's hard to be sure.

Here's a minimum reproducible example:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("Window", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 100, 100, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    
    while(1) {
        SDL_Event e;
        while(SDL_PollEvent(&e))
            switch(e.type) {
                case SDL_QUIT: {
                    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
                    SDL_Quit();

                    exit(0);

                    break;
                }
            }

        const char* err = SDL_GetError();
        if(err[0]) {
            printf("%s", err);
            exit(-1);
        }
    }
}
```

I understand that this is a strange issue(and a potentially unanswerable one) so I really appreciate any answers or suggestions.

I am using a MacBook Pro 13-inch Mid 2012 running macOS Catalina(10.15.6). Compiled using clang 12.0.0

EDIT: I have downloaded the SDL2 source code to look for the error and the root cause seems to be this function:

```
static int
SDL_GetTouchIndex(SDL_TouchID id)
{
    int index;
    SDL_Touch *touch;

    for (index = 0; index < SDL_num_touch; ++index) {
        touch = SDL_touchDevices[index];
        if (touch->id == id) {
            return index;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

I am in the process of looking for why exactly this error is triggered and will update this post for any future people who encounter this error as well as filing a bug report to the SDL dev team

Comment: From the [documentation](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetError): `The message is only applicable when an SDL function has signaled an error. You must check the return values of SDL function calls to determine when to appropriately call SDL_GetError().`

Comment: @RetiredNinja hence ```if(err[0])``` as SDL_GetError() will return \0 if there is no error to report - it won't exit unless there is a valid error and this error is only caused when the trackpad is touched so I don't think it's that. TY for positing though!

Comment: The point is that if nothing failed then asking for an error is just looking for trouble where there is none. It's the same as calling `GetLastError()` in Windows when a function succeeded. Many functions will initialize the error value up front even if they succeed so what you're looking at is invalid data.

Comment: My point is that there is code in place to handle arbitrary GetError calls in SDL - this is very much not what is intended to happen. Not only that but if this is so reproducible by me then why is there no documentation. I understand what you are saying but I do believe that this is an issue with SDL

Comment: @RetiredNinja So what I mean is: calling SDL_GetError() when no function has caused an error is not an undefined behaviour, it will return a length 1 string containing a null character. What I am experiencing is a bug. If you want you can try the minimum example on a non Mac machine and you will see that the returned error is always \0 (unless there is legitimately an error)

Comment: Since you've got the source, I'd say rebuild from it (with `-g`). Or, dunno about macos, but on other systems you can install the debug package that has the dwarf(?) debug symbols for the installed version. The error is actually set by `SDL_GetTouch`, so set a breakpoint on the `SetError` call line there: `SDL_SetError("Unknown touch device id %d, cannot reset", (int) id);`. Then, do stack traceback. Note that `GetTouchIndex` is _simple_ [does _not_ call `SetError`] and is called from [many] other functions where a -1 return is legit (e.g. `SDL_AddTouch`)

Comment: @CraigEstey It would appear that it's just a mouse event from the system, the root call (outside of my program) is just some apple lib stuff :/. I think I may just need to file a bug report to SDL...

Comment: Maybe you should log all `e.type` to a logfile to see if there's a strange progression. I'm a simple user of SDL, and my event loop doesn't check for errors. What happens if you move the `SDL_GetError` call inside your _inner_ `while` loop (i.e. you only call it if `SDL_PollEvent` returns true)?

Comment: @CraigEstey I don't believe errors are handled by SDL_PollEvent but I will check that tomorrow

Comment: Given that you've convinced yourself this is a bug, what sort of answer would you expect to this question? What is the actual question?

Comment: @RetiredNinja I am pretty sure it's a bug - but I am far from an expert on SDL or C for that matter -

Comment: I just looked through the entire SDL source code for examples of `SDL_PollEvent` [there are ~50] and _none_ of them call `SDL_GetError`. It may _not_ be valid to do so because [I _think_] the event queue is asynchronous to calls that set an error. IIRC, I wrote an SDL app years ago that was multithreaded and some of the drawing code was in another thread than the one for the event loop

Comment: *So what I mean is: calling SDL_GetError() when no function has caused an error is not an undefined behaviour, it will return a length 1 string containing a null character* no, `GetError` documentation specifically says the opposite. Where do you think error message is cleared? I know of some other places where err message is set but no error is signalled.

Comment: @keltar I see what you mean but I again must say that because the GetTouchIndex function is returning an aberrant value and that the error is only triggered on trackpad contact reproducibly and only on macOS without any documentation that I find this unlikely to be the issue.

Comment: @TTG I still have no idea what your question or complaint is, could you clarify that? Because it looks like "doc says I can't expect that result, but I really want to expect that, and then things go as doc says, which is a bug", and that doesn't sound too good does it? If your question is "why", then - thorough debugging is required, but it wouldn't change a thing. E.g. SDL have an optional code that reflects mouse movements to touch events and it could be a side effect of that part being disabled. What's actual TouchID you're getting?

Comment: @keltar So I have set some breakpoints in the SDL source and  it would appear that it is an issue with tracking mouse deltas on an unrecognised trackpad. Sdl tries to get the pointer ID but instead gets -1 and gives an error - this is an issue with my mac rather than macOS. I appreciate the postulation and the help but I guess Ill just set the program to ignore that error

Comment: I get the same error when doing the same thing, I guess the only option for now is to ignore it.